# Strict Standards. Помогите разобраться с ошибкой.

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Код выдает такую ошибку:
Strict Standards: Non-static method DbSimple_Generic::connect() should not be called statically in ...
Помогите разобраться с ошибкой, что нужно сделать?
Есть еще такая ошибка:
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in ...
Но эту проблема я решил путем удаления "&" из строки.

Comment: как я понял это не статичный метод, т.е. DbSimple_Generic::connect() тут не канает, надо юзать $obj = DbSimple_Generic; $obj->connect();


Хотя я могу ощибаться

Comment: > Но эту проблема я решил путем удаления "&" из строки.

Чувствуется рука мастера.

Strict standards в PHP - режиме повышенной строгости, который запрещает многие шорткаты, что должно привести к более целостностно написанному коду. Для начала стоит понять, нужен ли он вам, затем стоит переводить тексты ошибок и понимать, о чем они говорят. С текущими подробностями можно сказать, как вам обойти ошибки, но не как их решить.

Comment: Strict Standards: Non-static method DbSimple_Generic::connect() should not be called statically in...
Эта ошибка ссылается на данную строку:
DbSimple_Generic::connect($dbms.'://'.$dbuser.':'.$dbpasswd.'@'.$dblocation.'/'.$dbname);

Comment: @flauer9, а про нее @naym уже все сказал.

Comment: @Fike, @naym проблема не ушла, он по прежнему, выдает ошибку

Comment: @flauer9, судя по ошибке, вы не слеоаои то, что предлагал @naym. Нужно вместо

    DbSimple_Generic::connect($dbms.'://'.$dbuser.':'.$dbpasswd.'@'.$dblocation.'/'.$dbname);

Подставить

    $dbInstance = new DbSimple_Generic();
    $dbInstance->connect($dbms.'://'.$dbuser.':'.$dbpasswd.'@'.$dblocation.'/'.$dbname);